# Restricting property uniqueness without adding immutability with EF7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How would one restrict uniqueness on an entity property, and still allow updates on it? 
Adding the following constraint makes the property name immutable:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasAlternateKey(p => p.Name).HasName("AlternateKey_ItemName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure that property to be unique index.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasIndex(b => b.Name).IsUnique();
```

Comment: Would this work on defining uniqueness per multiple properties? As the example:  modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasIndex(b => new {b.SuperItemId, b.Name}).IsUnique();

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works for the project here as well.